# Android Gridview with 2 column (But different imageview width size)

Tags: android, dynamic, android-recyclerview, layout-manager, android-gridview

I want screen to look like following, with the help of gridview. I am able to add 1 column and two column using setSpanSizeLookup

But how to add two columns with dynamic width?

[image]

```
final GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(ExploreMenuActivity.this,2);
        gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                if(position == 0)
                {
                    return 2;
                }else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        });
```

Update :

I have used Flexbox layout by google .

```
implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.1'
```

My Main activity

```
 FlexboxLayoutManager flexboxLayoutManager=new FlexboxLayoutManager(ExploreMenuActivity.this);
        flexboxLayoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
        flexboxLayoutManager.setAlignItems(AlignItems.STRETCH);
  recycler_ExploreProduct.setLayoutManager(flexboxLayoutManager);
```

My .xml file

```
   <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/img"
android:layout_width="@dimen/_140sdp"
android:background="@color/color_white_gray"
android:layout_height="@dimen/_140sdp"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:src="@drawable/p_7" />
```

and My adapter

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {


    Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), aryImages[position], null);
    holder.bindTo(drawable, position);
 } 

 class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img); 
    }

    void bindTo(Drawable drawable, int position) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = imageView.getLayoutParams();

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        Log.d(TAG,"## bindTo before if");
        if (lp instanceof FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) {
            Log.d(TAG,"## bindTo inside if");
            FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams flexboxLp = (FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) lp;

           if (position == 0) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth / 3;

            } else if (position == 1) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth / 2;

            } else if (position == 2) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth / 2;

            } else if (position == 3) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth / 3;

            } else if (position == 4) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth / 3;

            } else if (position == 5) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth / 2;

            } else if (position == 6) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth;

            } else if (position == 7) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth / 3;

            } else if (position == 8) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth / 2;

            } else if (position == 9) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth;

            } else if (position == 10) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth / 2;

            } else if (position == 11) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth / 3;

            } else if (position == 12) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth;

            } else if (position == 13) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth / 3;

            } else if (position == 14) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth / 2;

            } else if (position == 15) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth / 2;

            } else if (position == 16) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth / 3;

            } else if (position == 17) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth;

            } else if (position == 18) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth / 3;
            } else if (position == 19) {
                flexboxLp.width = screenWidth / 2;
            }
    }
}
```

Right now I am able to achieve output using above static conditions,

How can I do this things dynamic, when my data will come from API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView

http://myhexaville.com/2017/02/27/android-flexboxlayout/

I am sure this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use stagard LayoutManager in Recyclerview to get the required results.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
package com.cfsuman.me.androidcode;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context mContext;

    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Request window feature action bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get the application context
        mContext = getApplicationContext();

        // Change the action bar color
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));

        // Get the widgets reference from XML layout
        mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        // Initialize a new String array
        String[] colors = {
                "Red","Green","Blue","Yellow","Magenta","Cyan","Orange",
                "Aqua","Azure","Beige","Bisque","Brown","Coral","Crimson"
        };

        /*
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager
                A LayoutManager that lays out children in a staggered grid formation. It supports
                horizontal & vertical layout as well as an ability to layout children in reverse.

                Staggered grids are likely to have gaps at the edges of the layout. To avoid these
                gaps, StaggeredGridLayoutManager can offset spans independently or move items
                between spans. You can control this behavior via setGapStrategy(int).
        */
        /*
            public StaggeredGridLayoutManager (int spanCount, int orientation)
                Creates a StaggeredGridLayoutManager with given parameters.

            Parameters
                spanCount : If orientation is vertical, spanCount is number of columns.
                    If orientation is horizontal, spanCount is number of rows.
                orientation : VERTICAL or HORIZONTAL
        */
        // Define a layout for RecyclerView
        mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // Initialize a new instance of RecyclerView Adapter instance
        mAdapter = new ColorAdapter(mContext,colors);

        // Set the adapter for RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   }
}
```

> ColorAdapter.java

```
package com.cfsuman.me.androidcode;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;


public class ColorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ColorAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private String[] mDataSet;
    private Context mContext;
    private Random mRandom = new Random();

    public ColorAdapter(Context context,String[] DataSet){
        mDataSet = DataSet;
        mContext = context;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ColorAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        // Create a new View
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_view,parent,false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataSet[position]);
        // Set a random height for TextView
        holder.mTextView.getLayoutParams().height = getRandomIntInRange(250,75);
        // Set a random color for TextView background
        holder.mTextView.setBackgroundColor(getRandomHSVColor());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return mDataSet.length;
    }

    // Custom method to get a random number between a range
    protected int getRandomIntInRange(int max, int min){
        return mRandom.nextInt((max-min)+min)+min;
    }

    // Custom method to generate random HSV color
    protected int getRandomHSVColor(){
        // Generate a random hue value between 0 to 360
        int hue = mRandom.nextInt(361);
        // We make the color depth full
        float saturation = 1.0f;
        // We make a full bright color
        float value = 1.0f;
        // We avoid color transparency
        int alpha = 255;
        // Finally, generate the color
        int color = Color.HSVToColor(alpha, new float[]{hue, saturation, value});
        // Return the color
        return color;
    }
}
```

> build.gradle [dependencies]

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

```
You need to use flexbox layout 
`<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
                android:id="@+id/flex_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:justifyContent="flex_start"
                app:alignContent="flex_start"
                app:alignItems="flex_start"
                app:flexDirection="row"
                app:flexWrap="wrap">
</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>`
```

> ```
> and then add view dynamically like
>  `TextView rowTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.flex_tv);
>   rowTextView.setTag(items.get(i));
>   rowTextView.setId(i);
>   rowTextView.setText(items.get(i));
>   flexboxLayout.addView(view);`
> ```

Please add  compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.0@aar' in your gradle

Comment: Hello thank you for posting, i hv tried this solution yesterday , no luck

Comment: let me know what problem you were facing if you are still struggling...

Comment: if i use FlexboxLayout then , classcast exception will occur, you only use Imageview inside row layout, but i need to align 3 imageviews on top of Center imageview, and that is not possible using Flex layout, and 2nd problem is i want to achieve zig zag layout posted in above question but till now, i can resize 1st two positions but not 3rd, Flexbox layout behaves strange

Comment: classcast exception is occuring because might be you are adding View to flexbox layout and when you are setting image to it, that time you are not type casting the view to imageview .. If you still have flexbox code you can post so I can check..   you can set background to flexbox layout and add padding to it so it can play your centerimageview roll..   I have achieved the same thing through flexbox.. although it took me a week..:)

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout with equal weight for both ImageViews Something like below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffff00"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```